# What is the better way to set defaults for optional

Tags: java-8, option-type

I have a model Object with so many Optionals.  That model object is used in whole transactions.
At the beginning of the transaction I need to put the default value in optional fields.

So
1 approach is to convert in an object with non optional values, but then I'll have a redundant class for  no reason. second approach is how I did below, but is there a better way to write `updateDefaults` method

```
class SampleRequest{
 Optional<String> a;
 Optional<String> b;
 Optional<String> c;
 Optional<String> d;
}


public void doSomething(SampleRequest sampleRequest){
 updateDefaults(sampleRequest)
 call other services    ...
}

void updateDefaults(SampleRequest sampleRequest){
 String aa= sampleRequest.getA().orElse("A"); // Application specific complex logic. values has to be set  
     sampleRequest.setA(Optional.of(aa));
    
    and so one....
}
```

What is the better way towrite updateDefaults method ?

Comment: if you are having default values for variables then what is use of `Optional` ?

Comment: Right... I removed them... earlier I had optionals and each subsequent services in transaction were handling  optionals  in their own manner... but now we got a generic rule engine to set default values at beginning, so removing optional and refactoring the underlying transactions code make sense.  I was being lazy and just setting at beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I'd potentially use a decorator

```
interface Request {
    Optional<String> getA();
}

class SampleRequest implements Request {
    private final String a;

    public Optional<String> getA() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(a);
    }
}

// Decorator
class DefaultingRequest implements Request {
    private final Request delegate;

    public Optional<String> getA() {
        return Optional.of(
            delegate.getA().orElse(DEFAULT_A)
        );
    }
}
```

Then any time you want the safety of the defaults, you can wrap your request.

```
return new DefaultingRequest(aSampleRequest);
```

---

You could alternatively introduce a new interface. The downside of this is that you can't treat `Request` the same as `FilledRequest`. The upside is that you know if the defaults have already been applied. With the above approach, you could wrap the same thing several times unneccessarily.

```
interface Request {
    Optional<String> getA();

    FilledRequest toFilledRequest();
}

class SampleRequest implements Request {
    //...

    public FilledRequest toFilledRequest() {
        return new FilledSampleRequest(this);
    }
}

interface FilledRequest { // the same as Request, but not Optional
    String getA();
}

class FilledSampleRequest {
    private final SampleRequest sampleRequest;

    public String getA() {
        return sampleRequest.orElse(DEFAULT_A);
    }
}
```